# Javascript: Setting img src with absolute path

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, image

I am trying to manually set the img src to a path on the filesystem, and then I want to draw that image on a canvas. I am using:

```
    var curr_canv = document.getElementById('c_main').getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();

    img.width = 525;
    img.height = 400;

    img.src = "..\AAAA\BBBB\CCCC\myimage.jpg";

    curr_canv.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

But nothing is drawn on the canvas after I do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `img.onload = function() { curr_canv.drawImage(img,0,0); }`? See [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch). "`Trying to call drawImage before the image has finished loading will... silently do nothing in Gecko 2.0 and later.`"

Comment: i don't think a person writing code using canvas do not know about basics of image inclusion in the javascript.

Comment: Is this code being served from a Web server (over `http://` or `https://`) or accessed locally via `file://`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the path to an absolute path *within your webserver*.
Javascript in the browser has no access to any filesystem.

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this in this way is that my goal is to have the user select a config.txt file with an OpenFileDialog. Then the code will parse that text file to read the image paths (I have this part working already) and show all the images, whose paths are listed in the text file. How would you recommend doing that?

Comment: @user1669641: You can't use an OpenFileDialog either.  **Javascript in the browser has no access to any filesystem**

Comment: If you're doing that in C#, you'll get a nasty surprise when you actually put that on a server.  You can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
\ 
(backslash)
```

instead of

```
/ 
(forward-slash).
```

JavaScript uses `\` as an escape character.

Comment: I changed the backslashes to forward-slashes, and that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the path has to be in the web folder or another accessible path.  You can see that you code works in general here: http://jsfiddle.net/pwm36/8/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "You can't do that."  Javascript running in a browser has no direct access to the user's file system.  This is a security feature of browsers in general.

There is a relatively new FileSystem API for HTML5, but it still probably doesn't give you what you want, because the browser is still "jailed".  You can't reach any files outside of the directory set aside by the browser.

You might consider the drag-and-drop API.  Users can drop files onto an area you designate, and I think you can access it with Javascript at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Like other have said you need to use a webserver delivered image. Or use the "file://" protocol.

Be carefull, loading an image ins an asynchronous tack you fant to draw only after the image has been loaded.

```
img.onload = function() {
   curr_canv.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#drawImage) for more info.