# javascript method not working

Tags: javascript

this code is not working as expected

```
<html>
<head><title>alert()</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function greeting()
{
var name=prompt("what's your name?","your name");
if(name){
alert("hi, " + name + " welcome to this page");
document.getElementById("im").src="F:\wallpapers\a.jpg";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="alert('hi, this is the alert() function');">
<img id="im" src="F:\wallpapers\Ubuntu_wallpaper__1_by_leroi14.jpg" onclick="greeting();" /></body>
</html>
```

document.getElementById("im").src="F:\wallpapers\a.jpg" is not displaying the image when given absolute path.
But it works if image is in same folder as this file.
can anyone help?

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server? Your image source really shouldn't ever include a drive letter.

Comment: i'm running it locally...the image is in another folder.

Comment: do you have an images folder ? you should use one, and put it inside your server folder. And then you can use something like : `src="/images/wallpaper.jpg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason you use backslashes in your path, which need to be escaped in string literals:

```
"F:\wallpapers\a.jpg" === "F:wallpapersa.jpg"
```

Use `"F:\\wallpapers\\a.jpg"` or `"F:/wallpapers/a.jpg"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on serving this page to others, you don't want to use an absolute path.  Javascript runs on the browser, and does not have access to the server's filesystem for absolute paths.

See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413546/javascript-setting-img-src-with-absolute-path)

It's common to have an images folder within your website's project folder. Put images in this folder, then you can use `src="/images/a.jpg"`